# How to prove the convergence of $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(\sin(x/2))^p} dx$ for $p<1$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-writing

I want to show that:  $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(\sin(x/2))^p} dx<\infty \space \text{ for } p<1$$

I was wondering would contour integration conversion help or not.

The problem can also be generalised and this is something I am interested in. For example, would the integral still converge if $x/2$ is replaced by $x$ or $2x$?

Thanks.

Comment: You do not need contour integration if you want to show the convergence, you can tackle this problem easily with much more simple techniques. Notice that the function is unbounded in a right neighborhood of $x=0$ and in a left neighborhood of $x=2 \pi$. How does the sine behaves in a right neighborhood of $0$? Can you make a clever substitution for a left neighborhood of $2\pi$?

Comment: @Bernkastel Could I use $x/2=arcsin(t)$?

Comment: I was thinking about $y=2\pi-x$, so you can study a left neighborhood of $x=2\pi$ as a right neighborhood of $y=0$. You now have $\sin(x/2)=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi-y}{2}\right)=\sin(\pi-y/2)$ and you can use trigonometry to write this in a different form, similar to what happens for $x=0$.

Comment: @Bernkastel I am confused as to how that substitution could help me with solving the integration.

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the integrand function $x\mapsto \frac{1}{(\sin(x/2))^p}$ is unbounded only in a right neighborhood of $x=0$ and in a left neighborhood of $x=2\pi$ and the integration interval is bounded. So, we can study:
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\left(\sin(x/2)\right)^p}\text{d}x$$
$$\int_\pi^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\left(\sin(x/2)\right)^p}\text{d}x$$
Observe that $\sin(x/2)=x/2+\text{o}(x)$ as $x \to 0^+$, hence $(\sin(x/2))^p=x^p/2^p+\text{o}(x^p)$ as $x \to 0^+$. From this, our first integral behaves like:
$$2^p \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{x^p}\text{d}x$$
Which famously converges if and only if $p<1$.

For the second integral, put $y:=2\pi-x$. So, $-\text{d}x=\text{d}y$ and when $x \to (2\pi)^-$ we have $y \to 0^+$. Noticing that $\sin(\pi-y/2)=\sin(y/2)$, the second integral behaves exactly like the first and so it converges if and only if $p<1$. In conclusion, the initial integral converges if and only if $p<1$.

Comment: Okay got it. So, for example, if I take $x$ or $2x$ instead of $x/2$, then this method won't work as unboundedness is not at limits, right?

Comment: It doesn't change anything to change $x/2$ by $x$ or $2x$. It only change the set of points where your funciton has singularities, but the method is the same and the answer is the same too.